# extract string within braces after a matching text and store in as a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have a several lines in my file like below

```
DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('SUN') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE
```

The text within parenthesis do change for every line. I am trying to extract the text within parenthesis after MANAGER (in this case SUN), store it as a variable and replace is with planet.SUN.star.

I tried awk field separator to extract text between parenthesis with field separator as parenthesis, but I my results are not consistent. I sometimes dont get the text within parenthesis after the matching word MANAGER.

Desire output is like below

```
 DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('PLANET.SUN.STAR') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE
```

Comment: updated the original question with desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Perl` is your option, please try:

```
word="MANAGER"
replacement="PLANET.SUN.STAR"
perl -pe "s/(?<=${word}\(')(.+?)(?='\))/${replacement}/" <<< "DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('SUN') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE"
```

which outputs:

```
DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('PLANET.SUN.STAR') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE
```

- The regex `(?<=${word}\(')` is a lookbehind assertion to match `MANAGER('`.
- The regex `(?='\))/` is a lookahead assertion to match `')`.
- The regex `(.+?)` in between is a pattern to be replaced.

I don't think you need to assign `SUN` a variable just for the replacement purpose but if you need it, the modification of the code is easy.

**EDIT**

Here's the updated version with an assumption of OP's requirement.

```
perl -pe "s/(?<=MANAGER\(')(.+?)(?='\))/PLANET.\$1.STAR/" text
```

Input text:

```
DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('SUN') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE
DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('MOON') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE
DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('JUPITER') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE
```

Output:

```
DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('PLANET.SUN.STAR') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE
DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('PLANET.MOON.STAR') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE
DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('PLANET.JUPITER.STAR') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE
```

- First of all, let us focus on the `MANAGER('blah')` part and break down the string into three pieces: `MANAGER('`, `blah`, and `')`.
- The regex `(?<=MANAGER\(')` matches the 1st piece. The regex `(?<=pattern)` is called *a zero-width positive lookbehind assertion*. It works as an *anchor* and the matched string is *not* included in the capture group. The nature is useful to re-use the original substring (1st piece) without affecting.
- The regex `(?='\))` matches the 3rd piece. The regex `(?=pattern)` is *a zero-width positive lookahead assertion*, which is similar to the 1st one.
- The regex `(.+?)` matches the substring surrounded by the 1st regex and the 3rd one. The `?` after the quantifier `+` causes the *shortest match*, otherwise the regex will try to match as long as possible across the word boundaries.
- New let's go on to the REPLACEMENT part. We want to add `PLANET.` in front of the captured word, and add `.STAR` after the word. The captured word can be referred by `$1` then the replacement part will look like `PLANET.\$1.STAR`. The backslash is required because the script is within double quotes.

Here's an `AWK` version as an alternative which yields the same result:

```
awk -v q=\' '$0=gensub("(MANAGER\\(" q ")([^" q "]+)(" q "\\))", "\\1PLANET.\\2.STAR\\3", "g")' text
```

Hope this meets the requirement.

Comment: The word SUN keeps changing for every line. It can be MOON or JUPITER

Comment: Would you please show the input and the desired output with adding a few lines? I'd like to know how the word in parens after MANAGER is re-used as the result.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer with a best guess and assumptions. Hope this meets your requirement.

Comment: I tried the perl and it worked great. Can you explain the solution please

Comment: Good to know it works. I've edited my answer to add some explanations for the Perl script. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

A solution with awk:

```
echo "DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('SUN') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE" \
| awk '{
    # Look for the field starting with MANAGER(
    for ( I=1 ; I <= NF ; I++ ) {
      if ( $I ~ /^MANAGER[(]/ ){
        MANAGER = $I
        break
      }
    }

    # Remove everything except our value
    sub( /^MANAGER[(]\x27/, "", MANAGER )
    sub( /\x27[)]$/, "", MANAGER )

    # Rebuild the line with the new value
    $I = "MANAGER(\x27PLANET." MANAGER ".STAR\x27)"
    print
  }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly trivial with `sed` and the use of a *capture group* and *back-reference* using the standard substitution form `sed "s/find/replace/"` where `find` contains the capture group `"MANAGER('\(.[^']*\)':` and `replace` uses the *back-reference* `\1` to insert what was captured, e.g.

```
sed "s/MANAGER('\(.[^']*\)')/MANAGER('PLANET.\1.STAR')/"
```

With your example, you would obtain:

```
$ echo "DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('SUN') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE" | \
sed "s/MANAGER('\(.[^']*\)')/MANAGER('PLANET.\1.STAR')/"
DEF QR('xxx.yyy.sss') USE(YES) DESC('Something') MANAGER('PLANET.SUN.STAR') NAME('CAT') TRASMIT('TRUCK') REPLACE
```

To capture `"SUN"` in a variable, you can use *command substitution* along with `grep -o` and a similar regular expression followed by *parameter expansions* to trim the outer single-quotes, e.g.

```
var=$(echo "your_string" | grep -o "MANAGER('.[^']*')")
var="${var#*\'}"
var="${var%\'*}"
echo "var: $var"
```

Results in the output:

```
var: SUN
```